# Unable to get the AD attributes with lowercase value?

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

How can I get the AD attributes that contain lowercase like: Wa, Co, ny, la

Using:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties State -Filter { (Enabled -eq $true) -and (State -cmatch '^[a-z]') } | Select SamAccountName, State | Out-GridView
```

The error is:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: ' (Enabled -eq $true) -and (State -cmatch '^[a-z]') ' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: -cmatch' at position: 
'34'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Properties State -Filter { (Enabled -eq $true) -and (Stat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Managemen 
   t.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: If `-cmatch` is not supported use flags: `State -match '(?-i:^[a-z])'` or `'(?-i)^[a-z]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63444821/9898643), you cannot use `-match` or `-cmatch` comparison operators in a filter.
Also, a filter should actually be a **string**, not a scriptblock (`{..}`).

In your case, you should add a `Where-Object` clause to be able to use regex after you have filtered on the `Enabled` property:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties State -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" | 
    Where-Object { $_.State -cmatch '[a-z]' } |
    Select SamAccountName, State | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 3):

The error clearly states the operator -cmatch is not supported. The filter in this instance is handled by the AD provider, so not all powershell operators are supported. Check with each specific PS provider. Here is a list you can use.
https://adsecurity.org/?p=297

Comment: thanks @doug. so how can I modify the script above?

Comment: Go see which operator would best fit your needs. If you want wildcard support go with -like or -notlike. If you don’t need it then -eq or -ne

Comment: already did -ceq, but the error is still the same: 
 Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: -ceq' at position: '34'.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Ceq is not on that list

Comment: I'm not sure AD cares about case, though it will respect the case attributes are set with.